# How do I change the default colors without addon software?

Tags: colors, default

I don't like the Orange and Purple color combination.  I can change it by adding thrid party applications to enable me to change it, but I'm thinking I shouldn't need to; I mean, the Orange and purple got in there somehow; I should just be able to change it with a hex editor os something to be the values I want.

How do I change it without a 3rd party package?

Using: Ubuntu 21.10

Comment: Hello. A good start to any question is to say what version of Ubuntu you are using. As written there is no way to assist you.

Comment: My bad.  Ubuntu 21.10

Comment: What color's are you taking about and where ?

Comment: Next Distro is having a FEW more color options, so we shall just wait and see at that point in a couple of weeks.